# Open source identity management repository?

Tags: open-source, user-management

Is there any open source identity management platform where we can use to centralize information with regards to the list of accesses an user has in the IT ecosystem? Moreover, if it provides the possibility to notify users periodically about their access in order to confirm if is still needed or not. Not looking for SSO or other functionalities, which are unfit for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

For business-critical applications Keycloak is mostly used. It's mature, based on Java.

In the self-hosting circles Authelia which is written in Go I think is being used and both fit your criteria perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A recent popular open-source IAM is Casdoor: https://casdoor.org/ , it's written in Go.

They also provide a SaaS hosting solution: https://casdoor.com/